# simple_form params ruby on rails; autofill resident variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

When a user clicks "add attachment" from resident show page, i'd like to autocomplete the field resident on form. We already know what resident they would like to add the attachment.

On the show page button, I pass resident params and these params are visible in the form url. Although the field is not completed.

```
http://localhost:3000/app/attachments/new?resident_id=2
```

Link on residient show page:

```
<a href="<%= new_app_attachment_path(resident_id: @resident.id) %>" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-sm">New attachment</a>
```

Resident model:

```
  class Resident < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid

  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :care_plans, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :incidents, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :letters, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sonas, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :progress_notes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :diagnosis_paragraphs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :room, optional: true

  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :date_of_birth, presence: true


  def full_name
    [first_name, middle_name, last_name].select(&:present?).join(' ').titleize
  end



end
```

Attachment form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([:app, @attachment]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :resident, label_method: :full_name, prompt: "Choose a resident", collection: Resident.order(:first_name) %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :document %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Author</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<%= @current_user.full_name %>" readonly value="<%= @attachment.author.try(:full_name) %>">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `attaachments#new` action, capture the `params` and set the *resident* as follows

```
def new
  @resident = Resident.find(params[:resident_id])
end
```

Now, set the value as `selected` like so

```
<%= f.association :resident, label_method: :full_name, prompt: "Choose a resident", collection: Resident.order(:first_name), selected: @resident.id %>
```

Comment: Like this?   def new
    @ attachment = current_business.attachments.new
    @ resident = Resident.find(params[:resident_id])
  end

Comment: @BenStrachan Yes, but make sure you dont have a space between `@` and `resident`

Comment: no error message, the Resident field on attachment form is unchanged

Comment: Try changing it to `default: @resident.id`

Comment: <%= f.association :resident, label_method: :full_name, prompt: "Choose a resident", collection: Resident.order(:first_name), default: @resident.id %>

Comment: @BenStrachan Apologies, its not default. It is selected. Try my updated answer

Comment: @BenStrachan Now delete the other question which you posted with the same problem. Duplicate questions attract downvotes.