# Auto complete field on simple form with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models 'activity_templates' and 'activity'. I want to create a link on the activity_template index to create a new activity. I want to send activity_template params to the active form. I want to autocomplete the activity_template field on new activity form.

I can't figure out how to pass the params on the index page.

I think its a problem with the link.

Link:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">Activities</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
      <table class="table table-bordered">

        <tbody>
          <% @activity_templates.each do |activity_template| %>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="<%= new_app_activity_path(activity_template_id: @activity_template) %>"><%= activity_template.name %></a></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="text-right">
        <%= will_paginate @activity_templates %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/app/activities/new
```

Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([:app, @activity]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.association :resident, label_method: :full_name, prompt: "Choose a resident", collection: Resident.order(:first_name), selected: @resident.id %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.association :activity_template, collection: ActivityTemplate.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id), prompt: "Choose an activity template", selected: @activity_template.id    %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.input :published_status, collection: ['Draft', 'Final'], default: 'Draft' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Author</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<%= @current_user.full_name %>" readonly value="<%= @activity.author.try(:full_name) %>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= f.input :data %>


  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Activity controller:

```
  def new
    @activity = current_business.activities.new
    if params[:resident_id].present?
    @resident = Resident.find(params[:resident_id])
    end
    if params[:activity_template_id].present?
    @activity_template = ActivityTemplate.find(params[:activity_template_id])
    end
  end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simple\_form params ruby on rails; autofill resident variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434240/simple-form-params-ruby-on-rails-autofill-resident-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to send activity_template params to the active form.

You should change `@activity_template` to `activity_template` in the link as you are iterating `@activity_templates` as `activity_template`.

```
<td><a href="<%= new_app_activity_path(activity_template_id: activity_template) %>"><%= activity_template.name %></a></td>
```

Now you should see `activity_template_id` value in the `url`

```
http://localhost:3000/app/activities/new?activity_template_id=value
```

As you already capturing the `params[activity_template_id]` in the `new`, the rest should work now.
Also I recommend using `link_to`

```
<%= link_to activity_template.name, new_app_activity_path(activity_template_id: activity_template) %>
```